# adding node.js application as a dependency to a java maven project

Tags: java, node.js, maven, dependency-management

is there anyway to append node.js application to java maven project as a dependency and to run it from inside the java maven project?

I know I can add it as a module inside the java project and run it via *ProcessBuilder*
but I got a requirement:1. this module will be built out of the java maven project and will be added to the java maven project as a dependency (with all the required node modules etc compiled inside ) 2. this module will be executed from the java maven project , is there any way to do that ?

Thanks.